# Matching of the impedance for the effect pedals

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, guitar-effects, effects-pedal

I have a Vox AC4 amplifier which lack of FX loop.

Hence, it is possible to add the effects only in front of the amplifier.
The chain would be: Guitar --> looper --> Reverb --> Amp

Because the looper is in front, it is important to match the impedance for the rest pedals:

From the looper I will have 330Ω of the output

HolyGrain which is stomp box has 680.000 Ω on input and 360Ω on the output
RV 300 which is modulatory pedal has 250.000Ω on input and 1.000 Ω on output

What is the better option assuming that I would like to send to Ac4 a very undisturbed in terms of frequencies range signal and ii) not lose the amplitude of the signal because AC4 lack of the head-room ?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, connecting low output impedance to high input impedance doesn't cause any problems. In any case the "mismatches" between 330Ω 680Ω and 1KΩ are not likely to be significant. Factors of 2 are important for speaker impedances,  because the *output* impedance of a good transistor amp is  0.01 ohms or less, not 4 to 16 ohms, so "turning the amp up to 11" can easily overload the amp if the speaker impedance is too low. But "overloading" a *line-level* output with an impedance of a few hundred ohms won't "damage" anything, whatever you do - the power levels are too low.

Comment: What about replacing speaker with more efficient one?

Comment: it's a tube amp which also has additional output for the another 16ohm cabinet. Here I ask because the difference in in/out impedance is much bigger in case of one pedal compared to another (I specify it in the first post now).. BTW is it possible to connect high-impedance headphones into the 16 Ohm  speaker output on amplifier?

Comment: @teodozjan What do you mean by "more efficient?" High quality speakers are often *less* efficient at converting electrical power into sound energy than poor quality ones. The point is that the maximum power the amp can send to the speakers is V-squared / R where V is the amp's internal power supply voltage (which is fixed!) and R is the speaker impedance. That means there is a *minimum* speaker impedance R that you can use safely, in the sense of turning up the amp as far you like (including creating distortion) but not frying it by taking too much power from the amp.

Comment: "Is it possible to connect high-impedance headphones into the 16 Ohm speaker output" That is not a good idea. On an "old-school" tube amp design, it may damage the amp simply because the output impedance is wrong (note, tube amps are different from transistor amps and effects boxes here), and if that doesn't happen, the amp can generate enough output to fry the headphones, or **permanently damage your hearing.** With phones the sound is generated *right in your ear* with close to 100% efficiency. A speaker cabinet is often less than 10% efficient, and several feet from your ears.

Comment: The difference between the input and output impedances of *one* device is irrelevant. They are two completely independent things. I'm talking about the output impedance of one device, connected by a cable to the input impedance of a different device.

Comment: The generally agreed "impedance standard" for line-level *professional* equipment is 600 ohms. Your range of numbers from 330 to 1000 are all "near enough for jazz" (or rock, heavy metal etc!) to that number. Electronic circuit design isn't done to several places of decimals, except in very specific situations!

Comment: This is all wrong. 1) **Do not** attempt to put guitar effect pedals anywhere after the speaker output of an amplifier. If you have no effects loop, you either live with that or have an effects loop professionally installed or buy a different amp. 2) Output impedances for pedals are *supposed* to be much lower than input impedances. They are **not** supposed to match. This is called "bridging" and creates the greatest voltage transfer, with very low current transfer. We want that. You can't match pedals to speaker jack. It is impossible.

Comment: @alephzero Efficiency has a specific meaning when it comes to speaker drivers. It is the measure of output SPL usually from 1 meter away while the driver is driven by 1 watt of a 1 kHz sine wave. So "more efficient" for a driver means "higher SPL measured at 1 watt and 1 meter". Trying to drive headphones from a speaker output would be very bad for at least one of the amp, the headphones, and the ears, and possibly very bad for all three.

Comment: Why it is imposible to connect reverb and looper directly into the AMP? For reverb, OK I understand it is a modulation of the signal -
 thus it's better to Instal it into the FX loop to isolate from the pre-amp. But the looper (and the distortion I guess) should works normally being plugged directly to the amplifier, doesn't it?

Comment: If you're asking if you can plug the **output** of the reverb and looper into the guitar **input** on the amp, then yes that is ok, there is nothing wrong with that. You don't even have to think about the impedances, they are correct, they shouldn't match. Matched impedances is bad for pedals, good for amp to speaker connections. If you're asking if you can connect the amp **speaker output** to the **input** of the reverb or looper, you can't because that will damage the amp, pedal, or both. Both the impedances and the power levels are wildly wrong for that kind of hookup.

Comment: @user3470313: you are getting confused here (or I am). YOur question is pretty straightforward, but then in a comment you mention hooking something up between the speaker and the amp. That is the Bad Thing Todd is speaking about. There is a lot of power there and things can break and even burn. Don't confuse speaker impedance matching with lowZ-hiZ input impedance matching.

Answer (score 2):

Don't over-think this.  Just hook them up and see what happens.  Low output impedence to high input impedence is good.  Inputs are about detecting voltage, not about transferring power.  If there's a problem or it doesn't sound good, come back and ask again.  But I don't think there will be.  These boxes are INTENDED to be used in-line with guitar inputs.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to clarify why the askers concerns are unfounded. It also could be misinterpreted to mean it's ok to connect the pedals in any way at all, such as to the speaker output of the amp.

Comment: I repeat - "These boxes are INTENDED to be used in-line with guitar inputs."
The concerns are unfounded because (a) LoZ out to HiZ in is good and (b) these boxes are designed to be used in-line with guitar inputs.